# Python - getting average from last 5 digits float objects

Tags: python, average

Reads file Qdata.txt and calculates the average of the values in 
  the 2nd column (or the 3rd column indeed, if date is considered as the 1st column

```
import sys

td = open("Qdata.txt", "r")  # opening the file to variable ("file handle") td

sum = 0
n = 0
firstround = True

for line in td:
    if (firstround):
        firstround = False  # nothing else is done for the first line (header)
    else:
        fields = line.split()  # This creates a list containing the strings on 
        # the line, by default separated by spaces or tabs.
        # Now fields[0] contains the date, fields[1] the 
        # 1st data value and fields[2] the 2nd one.
        try:
            sum = sum + float(fields[1])  # increasing the cumulative value
            field1 = (fields[1])

            print(field1)

            n = 5
        # Handling possible errors.
        except IndexError:  # IndexError occurs e.g. in the case of empty lines
            # (when fields[2], for example, doesn't exist)
            continue
        except ValueError:  # ValueError occurs e.g. if there are letters instead of 
            # numbers (when conversion to float causes an error)
            print("Incorrect values in the file.")
            sys.exit()
print("Average over the whole period was ", sum / n)
print("Total number of values was ", n)
```

This is the Qdata.txt

```
Date   3700300   6701500
20000101 21.00   223.00  
20000102 20.00   218.00  
20000103 18.00   218.00  
20000104 17.00   213.00  
20000105 17.00   210.00  
20000106 18.00   210.00  
20000107 21.00   210.00  
20000108 23.00   208.00  
20000109 27.00   201.00  
20000110 28.00   199.00  
20000111 26.00   196.00  
20000112 24.00   196.00  
20000113 23.00   194.00  
20000114 21.00   192.00  
20000115 19.00   185.00  
20000116 17.00   183.00  
20000117 12.00   179.00  
20000118 11.00   173.00  
20000119 10.00   171.00  
20000120 9.80   167.00  
20000121 9.00   165.00  
20000122 8.40   163.00  
20000123 7.50   157.00  
20000124 7.10   156.00  
20000125 6.70   150.00  
20000126 6.40   148.00  
20000127 6.00   148.00  
20000128 5.90   147.00  
20000129 5.50   145.00  
20000130 5.40   143.00  
20000131 5.30   140.00  
20000201 5.30   140.00
```

So, now I want the sum and later avg with numbers from field1. If I try to extract from field1[-5:], it does not work. What way can I get the last 5 digits of the middle column to sum and avg, I was thinking to make a list?

Comment: I don't think you're doing what you intend to do with `field1`. `field1` just holds the value of the current `fields[1]`. Are you looking to create a list from the middle column?

Comment: field1 = (fields[1]) makes field1 not a list, [-5:] only works on list. field1 = [] before the loop and field1.append(float(fields[1])) inside the loop.

Comment: You look like you're slicing a string; are you trying to average the last five digits of the string? Or the last five values seen in a column? Or something else? The question isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, I would like to make a list out of the middle column, would make it easier to get the last five digits, and sum them @Brett Beatty

Comment: If I try print(field1.append(float(fields[1]))) I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' @plasmon360

Comment: @FaF, did you do field1 = [] before the loop?

Comment: Yes, I would like the last 5 digits of the middle column, and avg them @ShadowRanger

Comment: It shows these if I try print(field1.append(float(fields[1]))) . @plasmon360 I added field1 = [] as you mentioned before the loop
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: `append` returns `None`, so `print`ing the result of it is pretty useless. You need to `append`, then `print(field1)` to see running values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm always a proponent of list comprehension. This one gets slightly more complex because you potentially omit some values, but it's still my preferred method.

```
def middle_item(line):
    try:
        return float(line.split()[1]), True
    except IndexError:
        return None, False
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect values in the file.')

with open('out.txt', 'r') as td:
    column = [value
              for line in td
              for value, is_valid in [middle_item(line)]
              if is_valid][1:]
    n = len(column)
    print("Average over the whole period was ", sum(column) / n)
    print("Total number of values was ", n)
    print('Sum of last five:', sum(column[-5:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brett Beatty answer to use list comprehensions, but if you want to know how to improve your original code you could do the following.

1) rename variable 'sum' to an other variable like "my_sum" because sum() is python in built function

2) create a list (field1 = []) before the loop and append to this list at every step of the loop. at the end of loop you will have a list with all the entries of the column.

3) you can calculate the average of the last five entries of the column by using inbuilt function sum(field1[-5:])/n

like shown below:

```
import sys

td = open(r"Qdata.csv", "r")  # opening the file to variable ("file handle") td

my_sum = 0
n = 0
firstround = True
field1 = [] # make an empty list
for line in td:
    if (firstround):
        firstround = False  # nothing else is done for the first line (header)
    else:
        fields = line.split()  # This creates a list containing the strings on 
        # the line, by default separated by spaces or tabs.
        # Now fields[0] contains the date, fields[1] the 
        # 1st data value and fields[2] the 2nd one.
        try:
            my_sum = my_sum + float(fields[1])  # increasing the cumulative value
            #field1 = (fields[1])
            field1.append(float(fields[1])) # add elements to the end of the list 
            n = 5
        # Handling possible errors.
        except IndexError:  # IndexError occurs e.g. in the case of empty lines
            # (when fields[2], for example, doesn't exist)
            continue
        except ValueError:  # ValueError occurs e.g. if there are letters instead of 
            # numbers (when conversion to float causes an error)
            print("Incorrect values in the file.")
            sys.exit()
print("Average over the whole period was ", my_sum / n)
print("Total number of values was ", n)
print("average of last 5 elements of field1: " , sum(field1[-5:])/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please refrain from using functions as variable name. In the following example I have renamed sum to sum1. I also implemented appending in the list and transforming the list afterwards to a numpy array. This makes computation much easier.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

td = open("Qdata.txt", "r")  # opening the file to variable ("file handle") td

sum1 = 0
n = 0
firstround = True
field1 = []

for line in td:
    if (firstround):
        firstround = False  # nothing else is done for the first line (header)
    else:
        fields = line.split()  # This creates a list containing the strings on 
        # the line, by default separated by spaces or tabs.
        # Now fields[0] contains the date, fields[1] the 
        # 1st data value and fields[2] the 2nd one.
        try:
            sum1 = sum1 + float(fields[1])  # increasing the cumulative value
            field1.append(float(fields[1]))

            print(fields[1])

            n = 5
        # Handling possible errors.
        except IndexError:  # IndexError occurs e.g. in the case of empty lines
            # (when fields[2], for example, doesn't exist)
            continue
        except ValueError:  # ValueError occurs e.g. if there are letters instead of 
            # numbers (when conversion to float causes an error)
            print("Incorrect values in the file.")
            sys.exit()


# transform list into numpy array
field1 = np.array(field1)

print("Average over the whole period was ", field1.mean())
print("Total number of values was ", len(field1))
print(field1)

print("Average over the last five periods was ", field1[-5:].mean())
```

You might want to look into the Pandas package if you want to work with importing txt files in python more often.